# Bind payments and auto return a certain amount of it with PayPal

Tags: payment-gateways

I had the idea to create a Drupal site with the feature of bid wars between two users in a certain product.

User A and User B will pay the same amount of money which will be bind in the website. Then both users will have something like a mini game between them and when both users mark the war as finished, both amount of money will moved to one of their PayPal account. Except of a fixed fee percentage.

Example:

- User A and User B pay 50$ each of them.
- After their "fight", user B wins and he gets 100$ - 2% fee= 98$.

Is there any way to do this automatically with the PayPal module or with another indirect solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this would get complicated with paypal .. as only a transaction is refundable .., and no 'payouts' are supported in commerce ..

why don't you convert payments to [userpoints](https://www.drupal.org/project/userpoints), and safe the paypal refund fee. and do the payout of the points on request manually or with [massrefunds.com](http://www.massrefunds.com/paypalDashboard/login.html) ?